# How do i prioritize which features to use in my machine learning model before the feature engineering stage?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing, exploratory-data-analysis

I am encountering a probably fairly common problem where I have too many features, lets say 500 possible features.

I only want to pick the top 10-50 features that would be the most predictive of y, or eliminate as many of them as I can before I do preprocessing. The reason for this is that I have 10 million rows, and a `sns.pairplot()` would obviously take forever. What are the comprehensive list of things I could do to exclude unimportant features, sorted from least computationally expensive to most computationally expensive?

This is specifically for before the modeling portion, we're not talking about `.feature_importance__` after a model has already been built.

Eg.

1. Highest correlated X's vs. y
2. Highest dispersion/variance within X
3. Use Lasso/Ridge
4. (computationally expensive) Recursive Feature Addition
5. (what else?)

Comment: I’m struggling to understand your rationale for eliminating features. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have too many potential features and want to eliminate some unimportant ones before fully processing them if possible

Comment: I get what you want to do. I don’t get why you want to do it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dave a reason could be for example  to reduce processing time .  Granted that the algorithm should have a way of penalizing/dealing with unimportant features automatically.  But processing time is a good reason to eliminate some earlier than the model training stage (especially when tuning has to happen as well).

Comment: Yes thank you @GeorgM.Goerg exactly. It is costly to put 10000 potential variables through the ringer, especially when each one has 1 million+ rows.

Comment: @Katsu how about just subsampling the data for a first training/tuning run to determine features via your favorite feature importance method; then train full model on subset selected In first step

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg i like that, thats a good call. sample first 100K rows and see